# Собрать данные по уникальным значениям датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

Задача такая: Дан `csv` документ, где отображены `id` (они иногда повторяются) и отзывы, которые оставил человек с этим `id`. Нужно собрать в новый датафрейм все отзывы, которые оставил человек с конкретным `id`.

Я действовала через grouby: `grouped_data = data.groupby('id').review.unique()`. Данные собрались как надо, но я не могу преобразовать их в отдельный датафрейм т.к. `id` и отзыв отображаются единым текстом.

Как поступить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для описанной вами задачи все проще - фильтрация с помощью булева массива

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 1, 3, 2], 'review': ['Текст 1', 'Текст 2', 'Текст 3', 'Текст 4', 'Текст 5']})
concrete_id = 2
grouped_data = data[data.id.eq(concrete_id)]
print(grouped_data)
```

```
   id   review
1   2  Текст 2
4   2  Текст 5
```

Пояснение. Сначала с помощью `data.id.eq(concrete_id)` создается булев массив (Series):

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

Далее с помощью `data[<булев массив>]` в новый фрейм выбираются все строки исходного, которые соответствуют `True` в булевом массиве. В данном случае - 1 и 4 строки.